# Trouble binding SelectedItem in ViewModel - MVVM Light Silverlight 4

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm-light

I am using SL4 with MVVM-Light Toolkit. I'm not sure what's going on here. I can't seem to find anything on the web that resolves this issue.. I have a user control that I incorporate into my MainPage.xaml using standard xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WorkOrder.Views" syntax, with a call to local:ListWorkOrdersView further down my page. Using a RelayCommand, I animate in that ListWorkOrdersView window when I click a "List Work Orders" button.

I have bound the data on ListWorkOrdersView to an ObservableCollection of test data (for blendibility). What I want to do is bind the SelectedItem of that RadGridView to a property in my ViewModel. If I place a breakpoint on the getter of the SelectedWO property, it fires when I load the control, but the breakpoint is NOT hit if I move it to the setter. Relevant code:

ListWorkOrdersView.xaml

```
<UserControl xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
    x:Class="WorkOrder.Views.ListWorkOrdersView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
      assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.SL4" 
    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions" 
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    DataContext="{Binding ListWorkOrders, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
  <Grid x:Name="master" 
    DataContext="{Binding ListWorkOrders, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
      <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="gvListWO" IsReadOnly="True"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataContext="{Binding wo}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=master, 
          Path=DataContext.SelectedWO, Mode=TwoWay}"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Width="440"
        Height="330"
       ItemsSource="{Binding}">     
    <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn 
           DataMemberBinding="{Binding WORK_ORDER_NUMBER}" 
           Header="Work Order Number"/>
   <telerik:GridViewDataColumn 
           DataMemberBinding="{Binding PROPOSED_BY}" Header="Proposed By"/>
   <telerik:GridViewDataColumn 
          DataMemberBinding="{Binding DATE_PROPOSED}" Header="Date Proposed"/>
      </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
    </telerik:RadGridView>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Relevant ListWorkOrdersViewModel.cs(removed code for databinding the gridview itself)

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging;
using WorkOrder.Model;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

namespace WorkOrder.ViewModel
{
    public class ListWorkOrdersViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public const string SelectedWOPropertyName = "SelectedWO";
        private ObservableCollection<BWorkOrder> _selectedWO;
        public ObservableCollection<BWorkOrder> SelectedWO
        {
            get
            {
               return _selectedWO;
           }
           set
           {
               if (_selectedWO == value) return;
                _selectedWO = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(SelectedWOPropertyName);
            }
       }
    }
}
```

Any ideas on why this isn't binding properly? I'm totally at a loss!

Comment: There's no use to bind the datacontext of the childwindow AND the dataconext of the grid both to the viewmodel. When you databind the datacontext of the usercontrol it goes down to all controls inside that usercontrol.
As for your problem, I can't really help you since you use telerik

Comment: Yeah I was playing around with datacontext as I was trying to figure this out. I didn't realize I still had that in when I posted this. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem lied with my property. It was set as an ObservableCollection, which is what I use, for example, to populate my DataGrid or RadGridView (telerik & non telerik). When I changed it to object, I was fine.